# Why does gsub/sub not work to replace ".."?

Tags: r

When I call rownames on my df I get something like this:

```
"Saint.Petersburg..Russia"           "Istanbul..Turkey"
```

This what I coded

```
gsub("..", " ", rownames(df))
```

This is what was returned

```
 [1] "            "      "        "          "
```

What I expected was

```
"Saint.Petersburg Russia"           "Istanbul Turkey"
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: `"."` is a special character in regex that matches any character. To match a literal period, you need to escape it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `fixed = TRUE` as `.` can match any character in the default regex mode if it is not escaped (`\\.`) or placed inside square brackets (`[.]`) or the faster option is `fixed = TRUE`

```
gsub("..", " ", rownames(df), fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "Saint.Petersburg Russia" "Istanbul Turkey"
```